# What is the meaning of phrase " ever up"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> And then disappears ever up.

What is the meaning of phrase "ever up"? From Harry Potter and the Cursed Child

Answer (score 1):

We can use 'ever' as a prefix before an adverb, meaning 'continuously without seeming to stop' - he disappears upwards, ascending constantly (not stopping or changing direction). In the following text, we read 'Scorpius hesitates for a moment. He makes a face. And then hoists himself up and disappears after Albus.'

> ever adverb (ALWAYS)
> continuously:
> United's record in cup competitions grows ever more impressive.

[Ever (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ever)